# Problem with publishing php website on IIS

Tags: iis, dns, windows-server, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm going to publish my iis website on a domain. So after adding the website and doing bindings, I've added a primary lookup zone and two hosts (ns1.domain and ns2.domain).
Afterward I've created two nameservers and assigned to the hosts.

I've put the nameservers and IPs on my domain DNS configurations.
Everything works fine in local but not through my domain.
It says :

> Server IP address could not be found. Try running Windows Network
> Diagnostics. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

When I enter my server's ip address it says :

> Not Found,
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

The 404 error happens even when I want to access the nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN is typically due to a misconfiguration or problem with your DNS. you can try the following ways to fix this error.

1. Release and Renew IP Address

   Due to the fact that this is usually a client-side DNS issue, the very first thing you should do is try releasing and renewing the IP address on your computer. This also includes flushing your local DNS cache, which is similar to browser cache. In Windows simply open up Command Prompt by pressing the Windows logo key and R. Then type “cmd” and hit Enter.

   Type in `ipconfig /release` and hit Enter. This will release your current IP address.

   Type in `ipconfig /flushdns` and hit Enter. This will flush your local DNS cache.

   Type in `ipconfig /renew` and hit Enter. This will renew your IP address.
2. Disable VPN and Antivirus Temporarily

   Sometimes VPNs and Antivirus software can conflict or override your network settings, including your DNS servers, etc. If you have any running, try temporarily disabling them (closing them) to see if it resolves the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error in browser.
3. Restart DNS Client Service

   If you’re running Windows you can try restarting the DNS client services which resolves and caches DNS domain names. Simply open up Command Prompt by pressing the Windows logo key and R. Then type “services.msc” and hit Enter. Scroll down to “DNS Client,” right click on it, and select “Restart.”
4. Change DNS Servers

   By default, DNS servers are automatically assigned by your ISP. But you could try temporarily changing these to a public DNS server.

Comment: I could not solve my problem using the above solutions. I'm unable to release or renew my ipconfig. it gives me an error. I think my problem is related to my DNS nameservers.

Comment: You can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to get more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved, I haven't added any hosts for "www"